# Check if in front of user/bearing in mapbox - andorid

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I just want to know if there is a way to notify the user if there is a marker in like.. 100 meters in front of them, and I mean in front the bearing/degree of the user.

just like:

[image]

Or if there is a way to attach a triangle polygon's top point to the bearing/degree of the user?

PS: I'm creating an app to reduce traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Mapbox Java SDK port of http://turfjs.org/docs/#bearing

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/docs/turf-port.md#measurement

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/services-turf/src/main/java/com/mapbox/turf/TurfMeasurement.java#L56

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/search?q=TurfMeasurement.bearing&unscoped_q=TurfMeasurement.bearing

Comment: Although  your answer it didn't help my aim, I created a very basic and complicated bearing check, I'll post the code when I Finalize.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem but with a collection of POI and solved in this way

```
Polygon sectorPolygon(@NonNull Point center, double radius,@FloatRange(from = -180, to = 180) double bearing1,@FloatRange(from = -180, to = 180) double bearing2 , @TurfConstants.TurfUnitCriteria String units) {
     List<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
     coordinates.add(center);
     coordinates.add(TurfMeasurement.destination(center, radius, bearing1, units));
     coordinates.add(TurfMeasurement.destination(center, radius, bearing2, units));
     coordinates.add(center);

     List<List<Point>> coordinate = new ArrayList<>();
     coordinate.add(coordinates);
     return Polygon.fromLngLats(coordinate);
 }

 FeatureCollection pointsWithinPolygon(FeatureCollection points, FeatureCollection polygons) {
     ArrayList<Feature> features = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < polygons.features().size(); i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < points.features().size(); j++) {
             Point point = (Point) points.features().get(j).geometry();
             boolean isInside = TurfJoins.inside(point, (Polygon) polygons.features().get(i).geometry());
             if (isInside) {
                 features.add( points.features().get(j));
             }
         }
     }
     return FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(features);
 }

void checkCustomPOIOnRoute(Location location, FeatureCollection poiCollection){
    double bearing=location.getBearing();
    Polygon sector=sectorPolygon(Point.fromLngLat(location.getLongitude(),location.getLatitude()),250, bearing-5,bearing+5,TurfConstants.UNIT_METRES);

    Feature sectorFeature = Feature.fromGeometry(sector);
    FeatureCollection sectorCollection= FeatureCollection.fromFeature(sectorFeature);
    
    FeatureCollection found=pointsWithinPolygon(poiCollection, sectorCollection);
}
```